# Rshiny: transforming selection of interactive InputSelect()

Tags: r, shiny-server, shiny

i got my first Shiny App working - at least nearly. The code works find and in simplified form looks like

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel('Tableau Workbook'),
  sidebarPanel(
  uiOutput("select")
  ),
 mainPanel(
 tableOutput("Columns1"))
 ))

shinyServer(function(input,output){
  output$select <- renderUI({
    selectInput("dataset", "Names", as.list(files))
 })

output$columns1 <- renderTable({
  f<- myfunction(input$dataset)
  f[[3]]
})
})
```

I need to modify "dataset" before it can be used in renderTable(). I tried

```
output$columns1 <- renderTable({
dataset<- lookuptable[which(dataset== lookuptable$table1),2 ]  
f<- myfunction(input$dataset)
  f[[3]]
})
```

The SelectInput shows a selection, from which the user can choose. What the extraline is doing: take the chosen item, look up the matching value in the lookuptable. This value is then fed into the function. The lookuptable is a dataframe with two columns and n rows..
However, when I add the extraline the visualization is broken. Has anyone an idea why?
Thanks a million for any help!

Comment: You're mixing up `input$dataset` and `dataset`.

Comment: @alistaire is right. First look up which table matches your input: `dataset<- lookuptable[which(input$dataset== lookuptable$table1),2 ]` and then pass this modified dataset to your function: `f<- myfunction(dataset)`

Comment: hi, thanks both of you!